# Why my custom table cell view does not "drawn"?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have followed this tutorial, I created a new empty project and all worked. When I wanted to integrate that to my macOS Swift/Storyboard application, the data is loaded, but there are no labels visible. It has been 3 days and I don't know what to do.

Here is a screenshot

https://preview.redd.it/no5f3ro280ba1.png?width=1840&format=png&auto=webp&v=enabled&s=e87e8d6d3d08c0b445b0da9ebbd4b578d22268e4

Here is my code https://github.com/ArtOS-Developper/alt-directe-macos

Thanks

PS : the target view is HomeViewController.swift its here where there is the code for the NSTable. ViewController.swift is just my login page

I am begginer in swift. I dont know I am supposed to do. I want to learn how to do that

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. 
The code should be included as code not a link

Comment: Check with your debugger that your `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` method is actually being called, and that it's returning a correct, non-nil NSView for the cell you're trying to display.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My function `func timeLineTableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?` must be just call `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?` and it worked !